# How to facebook like count logo work in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, facebook-like

I  am trying to work facebook like using Bootstrap, but it is not working and just go to facebook page, I want only facebook like count incement work in bootstrap, thank u

```
   <span class="item-meta">By <a href="#">xxx</a> <span class="pipe">|</span> <!-- <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> --> March 3rd 2014 <span class="pipe">|</span><a href="#"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up "style="font-size: 20px"></i> 10</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, do you just want a facebook like button, which increments when a user likes whatever it is. If so, this will work:

```
div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
</div>
```